# how to make the new input handlers (IPointerDownHandler, and so on) work on non-UI GameObject?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wrote a script like this:

```
public class LuaTap : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerExitHandler, IPointerUpHandler {

    #region IPointerDownHandler implementation
    public void OnPointerDown (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log ("down ");
    }
    #endregion

    #region IPointerExitHandler implementation
    public void OnPointerExit (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log ("exit");
    }
    #endregion

    #region IPointerUpHandler implementation
    public void OnPointerUp (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log ("up");
    }
    #endregion


}
```

when this script was added to a Non-UI GameObject, it does not work.
I prefer the new input handlers , but as far as I know it only works on new UI.

How to make it work on non-UI GameObjects?

Comment: does your gameobject have a collider component ? , and why don't you use :OnMouseDown, OnMouseUp and OnMouseExist functions ?

Comment: OnMouseDown functions need more coding. For example, OnMouseDown responses clicks through UI objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You game object has to have a collider. Then, ensure that you have [Event System](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-EventSystem.html) and a relevant Raycaster present in the scene. With UI system, the [Graphic Raycaster](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-GraphicRaycaster.html) is usually used, but I think that you might need [Physics Raycaster](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-PhysicsRaycaster.html) instead.

Comment: thanks. I tried as the demo says, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVZiv7DLU6E , and it says the same as you.  You are a great guy!

Comment: A new problem appears. Box Collider works, but Polygon Collider 2D or Box Collider 2D does not work. Polygon Collider 2D is necessary for path finding in my game.

Comment: I think you might get more help with that if you create a new question. Right now I only saw your comment because I have notifications for my answers, but everyone else would just see this as an old question with already accepted answer, and wouldn't open it to notice your comment. You want more than one person looking at your new question, this makes probability of getting an answer is much higher that way.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I will post a new question.