# GameObjects with Polygon Collider 2D or Box Collider 2D do not response clicks

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is a further question of this: [how to make the new input handlers (IPointerDownHandler, and so on) work on non-UI GameObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29940428/how-to-make-the-new-input-handlers-ipointerdownhandler-and-so-on-work-on-non/)

I did  the instructions as the accepted answer said, and it worked well.
but today a new problem appears. when changing the GameObject's Box Collider commponent to Polygon Collider 2D or Box Collider 2D, it does not response clicks.

Polygon Collider 2D is necessary for path finding in my game.

Comment: Once again, sorry for making you create a new question. I could've replied right away in this particular case, it's just a good practice in general to use this website like this, so you wouldn't rely on an individual user (me) but rather have an opportunity to get help from the whole community.

Comment: no need being sorry. glad you remind me the skills of getting help and thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using components with 2d physics, you should replace the raycaster you have (probably PhysicsRaycaster) with [Physics2DRaycaster](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Physics2DRaycaster.html).

Answer (score 0):

You would find a PhysicRaycaster Component on your MainCamera, it is used by 3d gameObject. To make effect on 2d gameObjects, you just need add a Physic2dRaycaster Component on you Camera. see this link for detail: [solution](http://www.reddit.com/r/Unity2D/comments/1xu43y/how_to_destroy_object_by_touch/)